# Getting error message in Edge 'JSON wire protocol command endpoint is not allowed' when server uses w3c

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge, webdriver-w3c-spec

When we run the script using Microsoft Edge getting the below error :

> The following JSON wire protocol command endpoint is not allowed when server is running in W3C mode.
>   GET /shutdown

What I understand is that Edge now supports W3C mode by default. Our Java binding is sending in Json wire protocol mode(JWP). How we can instruct to Microsoft WebDriver that use JWP mode instead of W3c mode

it was mentioned in the Microsoft documentation:

> w3c    Use W3C WebDriver protocol (default option) 17763 
>   jwp    Use JSON Wire protocol

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver

Could you please let me know how we can change from W3C mode to jwp mode?

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround is to specify an intermediate script for the Edge Driver which:

- Invokes the actual Edge Driver executable,
- passes all invocation parameters to it and
- additionally adds the "jwp" parameter.

For instance, I've created a batch file `edgedriver.bat` with following content:

```
C:\Windows\System32\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe %* --jwp
```

And on startup of my node I specify this batch file as driver for Edge:

```
java -Dwebdriver.edge.driver="D:\Driver\edgedriver.bat"^
     -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="D:\Driver\IEDriverServer.exe"^
     -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\Driver\chromedriver.exe"^
     -jar D:\Vaadin_Testbench_Node\vaadin-testbench-standalone-5.1.2.jar^
     -role node^
     -nodeConfig D:\Vaadin_Testbench_Node\nodeconfig.json
```

Comment: Wow thanks , how is batch file working in this case?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The batch file only acts as a proxy. Finally, it invokes the actual web driver executable and passes one additional parameter which we need (`jwp`).

Comment: like how, is bat file being recognized by the selenium jar. Do you have pointer to the source code selenium standalone jar file ?

Comment: I see. No, I'm sorry - I don't exactly know the underlying mechanism. At least, it _feels_ like that it simply _excutes_ the file. Since batch files are executable just like PE files, it works well.

Comment: ya thought the same , was just wondering how that thought of using a batch file and that two using % came to your . That was brilliant

Answer (score 0):

Try to add line below in file **EdgeDriverService.java**

```
argsBuilder.add("--jwp");
```

It can help web driver to launch in jwp mode.

Reference:

[selenuim server node 3.14.0 failed to start new session for Edge #6464](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6464)

Comment: Hi Deepak, edgedriverservice file is jar file how we can add the arg into the jar file

Comment: Looks like you need to forked that library to make this changes. you can also try to refer the last post from link I suggested in my previous comment.